# why does pg_size_pretty return negative value?

Tags: postgresql, bigint

I was playing with pg_size_pretty() and I've discovered that when I pass it a great value it starts to return negative value.
This is my test:

```
select pg_size_pretty(9223370000000000000); -- "8388606 TB"
select pg_size_pretty(9223371000000000000); -- "8388607 TB"
select pg_size_pretty(9223372000000000000); -- "-8388607 TB"
```

Can you explain me why?
Thanks.

Comment: +1 for finding a bug in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I've reported it one minute ago. Thanks again to everybody. :)

Comment: Bug fixed. http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2011-04/msg00189.php Regards. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The highest signed 64 bit int is 922337203685477587. That's but a tiny bit more than the number in question. Surely there's an overflow somewhere in `pg_size_pretty`.

Based on the code mentioned in a comment, `pg_size_pretty` is attempting to round the number and does so using an intermediary value that's larger than the max signed 64-bit int. 9223372000000000000 + 1024*1024*1024*1024/2 = 9223372549755813888, which is larger than 922337203685477587.

**Update**: Added second paragraph and clarified that the overflow isn't in the caller.

Comment: For extra reference-y goodness, here's the function in question in [dbsize.c](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/utils/adt/dbsize.c;hb=HEAD#l466)

Comment: @mu is too short, ok? Not sure why you point that out since I've already pointed that the error in `pg_size_pretty` 3 hours earlier.

Comment: +1 Hi ikegami. Thanks for your explanation. I'm using version 8.4. I don't know if the bug persists also in version 9.0. Thanks also to Jeremiah for source code link.

Answer (score 5):

You are not overflowing, `pg_size_pretty` is overflowing. The [`pg_size_pretty`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE) function is supposed to take a `bigint`:

> `pg_size_pretty(bigint)`
>   `text`
>   Converts a size in bytes into a human-readable format with size units

And `9223372000000000000 < 9223372036854775808` so `9223372000000000000` is a perfectly valid `bigint` and `pg_size_pretty` should do The Right Thing with it. You should report a bug to the PostgreSQL people and win kudos.

**UPDATE**: Examining the PostgreSQL source code (thanks to Jeremiah Peschka for providing the link) shows us where the bug is:

```
491                 else
492                 {
493                     mult *= 1024;
494                     snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), INT64_FORMAT " TB",
495                              (size + mult / 2) / mult); /* OVERFLOW! */
496                 }
```

If `size` is close to the limit of `int64`, then adding `mult/2` to it will overflow before the following division by `mult` can bring it back into range.

Comment: Damn, Mu.  You're on fire tonight.

Comment: Scotch bonnets, eh? I usually end up with Serranos.

Comment: +1. Hi mu. Thanks even to you. You're always very kind. I've accepted ikegami's answer because he answered first. Thanks again to all. I love this site. ;)

Comment: Hehe, thanks Mu. Good answer. I just like using this as an excuse to learn more about how PostgreSQL works.